# Rails - given a create_at time stamp, I need to know if it is from today or from the past?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date, timestamp

I'm working to create an email alert that only sends out if X.created_at is from yesterday or older.

I don't want to alerts going out a day.

Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything before midnight last night:

```
ob.created_at.to_i < Time.now.beginning_of_day.to_i
```

Anything before 24 hours ago right now:

```
ob.created_at.to_i < Time.now.to_i - 86400
```

Comment: undefined method `at_begging_of_day

Comment: @AnApprentice: That's a typo, sorry. I edited it to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use ruby's `Date.yesterday.to_time.to_i`

like

```
send_email if ob.created_at > Date.yesterday.to_time.to_i
```

Comment: Not sure how this work? Date.yesterday.to_time.to_i
 => 1318921200   where is the 1 day part?